# Good definition of (terminal) singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I'm beginning to study the singularities in the minimal model program on Matsuki's "Introduction to the Mori Program". Can someone tell me why the definition of terminal singularities (for instance) is well posed?

More precisely, if X is a normal projective variety s.t. $K_{X}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier, we say that it has terminal singularities if there exists a projective birational morphism $f:V \longrightarrow X$, with $V$ nonsingular, s.t. in the ramification formula $$K_{V}=f^{\star}K_{X}+\sum a_{i}E_{i}$$ all the coefficients $a_{i}$ are strictly positive. How can I show that this is independent from the $(f,V)$ chosen?
Thank you!

Comment: No time for a complete answer right now, but here's the idea: suppose you have two resolutions, one satisfying this condition but not the other. Find a resolution dominating both of them, and compare the coefficients of the $E_i$ in the canonical bundle of that variety.

Comment: If $g:V'\to V$, then $K_{V'}=g^*K_V+\sum b_jF_j$ where $b_j>0$ as $V$ is smooth and hence terminal and $F_j$ are the excetionals. But then $K_{V'}=g^*K_V+\sum b_jF_j= g^*(f^*K_X+\sum a_iE_i)+\sum b_jF_j=(f\circ g)^*K_X+g^*(\sum a_iE_i)+\sum b_jF_j$ where $g^*(\sum a_iE_i)+\sum b_jF_j$ is exceptional with coefficients $>0$. Finally if $W\to X$ is another resolution, then we may assume that $V'\to X$ factors via $h:V'\to W$, $k:W\to X$. But then $K_W=k^*K_X+h_*( g^*(\sum a_iE_i)+\sum b_jF_j)$ where the coefficients of $h_*( g^*(\sum a_iE_i)+\sum b_jF_j)$ are $>0$.